# Reading csv file to python ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, csv

Any help with this would be appreciated. Please keep in mind that I am a beginner in Python. This is the portion of the code that I am having trouble with:

```
__author__ = 'peter'



from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv


TICKER='CHTR'
STDEV_FILE = TICKER + '_stdev.csv'
TRADES_FILE = TICKER + '_trades.csv'
DATETIME_CSV_FORMAT = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'

def read_data(csv_filename):
  result = {}
  with open(csv_filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
     header = reader.next()
     #print 'HEADER',header
     for row in reader:
        new_data=None
        if len(row)==6: # this is a QUOTES file
          ticker, date, time, price, rtn, standard = row
          rtn = float(rtn)
          standard = float(standard)
          new_data = [rtn, standard]
        else: # assume this is a TRADES file otherwise
          ticker, date, time, price, size = row
          price = float(price)
          size = int(size)
          new_data = [price, size]

        date_object = datetime.strptime(date +' '+time, DATETIME_CSV_FORMAT)
        if not ticker in result:
          result[ticker]=[]
        result[ticker].append([date_object] + new_data)
  return result

vol = read_data(STDEV_FILE)
trades = read_data(TRADES_FILE
```

)

When I run it this is the error I recieve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peter/PycharmProjects/Vol/Vol.py", line 39, in <module>
    vol = read_data(STDEV_FILE)
  File "/home/peter/PycharmProjects/Vol/Vol.py", line 25, in read_data
    standard = float(standard)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: #DIV/0!
```

I have run this on other csv files and had no trouble.

Here is a small sample of the csv file:

```
SYMBOL  DATE    TIME    PRICE          RTN                     STDEV
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CHTR    20130718    9:30:00 124.66  0                0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CHTR    20130718    9:30:00 124.66  0                0.0005674559
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CHTR    20130718    9:30:00 124.56  -0.0008025039        0.0004539101
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CHTR    20130718    9:30:00 124.54  -0.0001605781        0.0001135459
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CHTR    20130718    9:30:00 124.54  0                0.0070177722
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CHTR    20130718    9:31:56 123.310 -0.0099246286        0.011065531
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CHTR    20130718    9:34:05 124.018 0.0057243955         0.0040363557
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Ultimately I would like to plot the standard deviation on y axis and seconds from midnight on x axis. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to identify the line that is causing the problem?  For example, you could split the file in half, and see which half it still has the problem with, and keep repeating until you narrow it down to the offending line.

Comment: That's not a CSV file.

Comment: Also, some things don't convert to floats easily (or at all) I'm assuming it's getting some sort of data that it can't handle and saying "screw it."  Put a print statement ahead of the offending line to see what it's trying to convert when it fails.

Comment: I copy and pasted the csv file. The it is difficult to format. It is a representation of the information in the excel file.

Comment: CSV stands for "Comma Seperated Values", though you can really use any delimiter...  but your file is just a text file formatted to look like a table.

Comment: I am reading in an excel csv file into python. What I have shown is a sample of the data.  The last column is the one that is receiving the error.

Comment: using debug:  ['CHTR', '20130718', '16:00:00', '124.53', '-0.0003211562', '#DIV/0!']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to convert the string "#DIV/0' to a float. Obviously this is not possible. The cause of this is attempting to divide by zero somewhere in your excel/csv sheet. Look back through your excel sheet and see if anything is divided by zero and change it.

Alternately you could implement a simple if statement:

```
if standard == '#DIV/0':
    print 'Error'
else:
    standard = float(standard)
```

EDIT: Some references: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/correct-a-div-0-error-HP010066245.aspx

Comment: Please look at the reference. The #DIV/0 error can be caused by a number of things such as referencing to empty cells. Either way the issue is with the excel sheet and not with your code. The code is reading in '#DIV/0' so that value is already in the excel sheet. Open the CSV in a text editor and look at the line causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "if standard == '#DIV/0':", it might be easier and more readable to do:

```
 if standard.isdigit():
      standard = float(standard)
 else:
      # error code
```

str.isdigit() will check all the characters in 'str' to see if they are digits.